# Base64 encoding of String in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, base64, qt5

I am trying to base64 encode a `QString` in Qt5 . However, I am getting an error saying `identifier not found` on line `QString b64string = base64_encode(src);`

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QBitArray>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    QString src = "Hello";
    QString b64string = base64_encode(src);

    qDebug() << "Encoded string is" << b64string;
    return a.exec();
}

QString base64_encode(QString string){
    QByteArray ba;
    ba.append(string);
    return ba.toBase64();
}
```

Why is the error occurring? can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: You need to have a function prototype for `base64_encode` up above the call somewhere.

Comment: u mean something like QString base64_code(QString string); ?? . Above the main function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The identifier it can't find is `base64_encode`. This is because it doesn't come until later in the file. The usual way of preventing this error is to put a function prototype at the beginning of the file or in a separate include header:

```
QString base64_encode(QString string);
```

You could also just rearrange the code so that anything depending on the definition comes last, i.e. move `main` to the end.

Answer (score 18):

The problem you face is what Mark Ransom said , just change the order of the functions or write a function prototype at the beginning of the file to solve your issue. but When i want base 64 i usually do this

```
QString src = "Hello";
src.toUtf8().toBase64();
```

so you do't have to write a custom function .